# Help new users with *effectively placed* guidance

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

(I wrote [this](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/any-way-to-add-prominent-link-to-on-off-topic-guidelines) and was pointed here to Meta.)

At [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) we get very many questions which are off-topic, typically for being homework, repeats, or not fulfilling the non-obvious but quite strict guidelines (networks should be professionally managed, professional equipment etc).  Surely many other sites have the same issue.

One important reason for this is that the "Ask Question" button is right in your face; "What to ask" is at least three clicks away.  We say **PLEASE ASK**, without caveats, and then, often within minutes, we say **BUT NOT THAT**.

This is incredibly frustrating for the new people, who immediately (and sometimes volubly), form the impression it's unwelcoming.  It's hard to say they're wrong.

This is not a new observation: a year ago it was considered [Time To Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

**Please can we put some How-To-Ask help somewhere *effective*.**

All I'm suggesting is link next to the "Ask Question" button, perhaps labelled "What to ask" or "Guidance".  (Others have suggested [something clever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135738/provide-new-users-with-specific-context-sensitive-guidance-when-writing-questio), but I'm just talking about basic user experience competence: *most* new users are doing it "wrong", that means we should explain better/clearer/ differently/elsewhere).

Comment: You might be interested in the [Ask a Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live).

Comment: @Glorfindel thank you ... is that only for Stack Overflow and not the other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: According to [2018: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321318/369973), 55.63% of questions asked on Network Engineering were closed. Of the 2,921 questions closed, 2,156 were closed as off-topic.

Comment: Only for Stack Overflow at the moment.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog thanks.  It looks interesting, but special purpose.  A link "What can I ask about?" right next to "Ask Question" might well work fine and would work for all the sites.

Comment: The sidebar on the Ask page can be customized too... [Here's an example of how to ask for that](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/our-how-to-ask-sidebar)

Comment: The percentage of people who ask a bad question because they couldn't find information on how to ask a good question is *dramatically* lower than the percentage of people who didn't ask a good question because they were entirely disinterested in taking the time to ask a good question.  The system *already* thrusts the how to ask guidelines in new users faces pretty aggressively.  They're ignoring it.  I'm not really opposed to being even more aggressive about it, but I don't expect it to improve question quality so much as make it easier to say, "I told you so" when they continue to ignore it.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks ... who can change the "how to ask" text and how do they do it?

Comment: Employees, based on a request on your meta, @jonathanjo. Come up with some useful, *succinct* guidance in the style already used on the page and we'll try & work it in.

Comment: @Servy According to a [famous micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/), it was shown that people ask bad questions because 1. we (as a whole across SE) don't make our guidelines initially clear (only one of the 20 participants saw a help center, and that wasn't via the top bar link), and 2. the positioning of the sidebar on the right side makes people overlook it, and the small proportion of participants who saw it only saw it after already composing their question (and thinking, "they won't mind, right?").

Comment: @Shog9 Have you considered that a large proportion of users [overlook the sidebar due to its placement on the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study) (possibly due to the natural left-to-right reading direction), and if they later notice it and it makes their question off-topic, they tend to think, "they won't mind, right?"

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I absolutely believe that people didn't even see the help center.  But it *is* shown to people really forcefully.  That people are shown a screen just telling them to read the guidelines, and they click through it without reading it, just means that *no matter how intrusive you are, many users won't read the guidelines*.  The solution to the problem isn't to make them *more* intrusive, as it just makes people annoyed at having to dismiss some intrusive message they're not going to read.

Comment: @Servy ... yes, certainly being intrusive doesn't help, and I find the "similar question" are never similar (so that's just accept-conditions intrustion), but our current NE How to Ask is just noise because it contains no NE-type words.   It's in the right place, if it has keywords (and very importantly, links) it might help if can find a good spot between too short to be useful and too long to be read.  I am eternally optimistic.

Comment: If the most common problem is that people are posting off topic questions then perhaps the most pertinent place to add information is in the site's name. Perhaps the name "professional network engineering" would lead people to understand the topic most quickly.  I don't believe "Electrical Engineering" and "Software Engineering" are as strict about homework questions.

Comment: @PhilipCouling thanks for suggestion: I don't disagree with you -- I made exactly a similar suggestion when we were discussion this issue recently -- but for a number of reasons it's tricky.  The task I was on today was trying to find something we could definitely do which ought to help at least a bit.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, [sf] has the same type of problem that it is for professionals, but people ask about home servers and such there. I have noticed that even on [so], when someone posts a homework question, it gets down voted and closed. I think all the sites want you to try to work it out. The biggest problem on NE I think are the home users that want network engineers to help with the home networking problems, but that was the big reason to split NE off from [su] and [sf]. I have no problem helping a student with a concept, but I'm not doing his homework for him.

Comment: @RonMaupin I agree ServerFault does have a similar problem.  I disagree on the root cause how to fix it.  I read [Time To Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) very differently.  I read: *We are blaming new users for being new*.  Fundamentally if people are misunderstanding the scope of a website, that's a problem with either *branding* or *choice of scope*.  Rather like a door which physically looks like a "Pull" people will pull it and only then read the sign saying "Push".  Adding more words saying Push won't help.

Comment: Let me tell you, as a recently new user I wholeheartedly agree that the do's and don't of question asking need to be clearer

Comment: @PhilipCouling, here is a good example of us helping someone learn and pass a certification exam by answering concept questions, rather than specific "_education, certification, or homework_" questions: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/58748/8499

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options right now:

- Customizing the guidance on the Ask page itself: [Our 'How to Ask' sidebar](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/our-how-to-ask-sidebar)

  *Good place to remind folks what the site is about and link to resources they'll find useful while composing a question*
- An interstitial: [Should folks have to click through an interstitial page to ask questions on Server Fault?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5850/should-folks-have-to-click-through-an-interstitial-page-to-ask-questions-on-serv)

  *This seems to work best when folks are asking questions that might be on-topic but just need a few pointers, or especially **another reminder to search first**. If you're primarily closing questions as Off Topic instead of Duplicate, it probably won't help much.*
- Content-sensitive warnings: [Do we want tag alerts for font-identification and critique questions and how should they be worded?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/do-we-want-tag-alerts-for-font-identification-and-critique-questions-and-how-sho)

  *If your problems are focused around specific tags or keywords, these can provide much more targeted guidance than is possible with the other options*

In the future, we may be able to offer customized [Ask Question Wizards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live) as well, but this isn't possible now.

Comment: Based on your statistics, NE closes over half its questions as off-topic, so there is certainly a problem. We try very hard to guide the users to the proper site when putting an off-topic question on hold, and we seem to bend over backwards to rehabilitate other questions. The (subjective) division between people who thanks us for pointing to a better site, and those who get belligerent and simply demand the question be answered seems to be about evenly split. People will spend days arguing to reopen a question that would have been answered on the correct site in very short order.

Comment: @shog9 Thanks that's very helpful, I've put a question up on NE-meta with a suggestion. https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/856/what-should-we-have-in-ne-how-to-ask-box

Comment: Lifting the ban on telling users what ***not*** to do would help.

Comment: @PeterMortensen couldn't agree more

Answer (score 2):

Spinning out a comment into an answer...  I don't really agree with the problem as described though I do believe there is a problem.

---

I read [Time To Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) very differently.  The crucial piece of this for me is

> **Let’s make it easier for new users to succeed**. No, I’m not shifting the blame. We set them up for failure, and our power users have been asking us to help them for ages. We’re planning to test a new “beginner” ask page that breaks the question box into multiple fields – one for each of the key things answers need to help

One interpretation of this is "give more guidance".  A "better" interpretation is "don't set people up to fail".

To explain the difference:  Most of us have had the experience of pulling on a door only to read the word "Push".  Was the word "Push" unclear?  Was it in the wrong place? [Or did the door look like a "Push"?](https://99percentinvisible.org/article/norman-doors-dont-know-whether-push-pull-blame-design/)  If the design regularly leads people to believe the wrong thing, then no amount of documentation will help.

This is fundamentally the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

---

Now to talk about [Network **Engineering** (SE)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions).  I've never visited this site before now.  I find it surprising that Network Engineering is a "professionals only" site where [Electrical **Engineering** (SE)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and [Software **Engineering** (SE)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) are not.  Indeed event [**Engineering** (Beta SE)](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour) isn't.

A link to "What to ask" is already too late because the new user has already decided what to ask.  Arguably "Is this the right place to ask?" is better but it still has the problem that new users have already decided that it is, much like a door that says "Push".

I'll admit that I'm deeply disappointed by the community choosing to have "professional only" sites.  We're here to help people learn, why do we turn away those who have not yet learned?...

...But if we must have them then, *please*, lets make it clear in the branding.  Why not a simple name change to "Professional Network Engineering"?

Comment: Thanks for interesting suggestions.  My task I was trying to achieve with this question was to find out how we change the guidance *within the current parameters*.  I completely agree there are other, more important issues, about remit.  I also think all the "affordances" are pointing in the wrong direction.